# How to get just one Checked node's texts in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I have a TreeView with checkboxes like this:

```
□2D
---□AAA
------□AAA  12
------□AAB  23
------□AAC  9
```

I want to learn, for example, AAC node (with name) was checked or not.

Just the letters important here, numbers not important, so I'm trying split:

```
Dim strarr() As String
StrArr = TreeView2.SelectedNode.Text.ToString.Split(" ")
Selection(StrArr(0)) = True ' I want to set a boolean array like this
```

Above code, just working TreeView_AfterSelect event, but not working TreeView1_Click event. In default TreeView control,  There is no event like "TreeView_Checked" event.

How can I get directly (un)Checked node's "text" in VB .Net? Without loops (no need to learn all the nodes checked or not, just one node's name needed) or recursive method.

Comment: `There is no event like "TreeView_Checked" event`.  Try [TreeView.AfterCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @LarsTech, It worked, Thank you.